# Python Comparing Values of Numpy Array Between 2 Dictionaries Value

Tags: python

I have 2 dictionary and an input

```
letter = 'd'

dict_1 = {"label_1": array(['a','b']), "label_2": array(['c','d']), ...}
dict_2 = {"label_1": array(['x','y']), "label_2": array(['z','o']), ...}

letter_translated = some_function(letter)
```

output desired: 'o'

What I have in mind right now is to get the index number from the array of the key `"label_2"` in `dict_1` then searching for the same index in `dict_2`. I am open to other way of doing it. If you are unclear about the question, feel free to drop a comment.

Note: the arrays are numpy arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to iterate through the first dictionary, while keeping a trace of how to get to the current element (`key` and `i`) so that we can look in the second dict in the same place:

```
from numpy import array

dict_1 = {"label_1": array(['a','b']), "label_2": array(['c','d'])}
dict_2 = {"label_1": array(['x','y']), "label_2": array(['z','o'])}


def look_for_corresponding(letter, d1, d2):
    for key, array_of_letters in d1.items():
        for position, d1_letter in enumerate(array_of_letters):
            if d1_letter == letter:
                return d2[key][position]
    return None # Line not necessary, but added for clarity


output = look_for_corresponding('d', dict_1, dict_2)
print(output)
# o
```

Of course, this code will fail if `dict_1` and `dict_2` do not have exactly the same structure, or if the arrays are more than 1D. If those cases apply to you, please edit your question to indicate it.

Also, I am not sure what should be done if the letter is not to be found within `dict_1`. This code will return `None`, but it could also raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'index'? The number?

dictionaries don't have the concept of counted indices of their entries. You can only access data through the key (here "label_2"), or by iterating (`for key in dict_1 ...`).

The order is not guaranteed and can change. The order or your declaration is not kept.

If you wish to have "label_2" in both, then you need to access

```
key = "label_2"
item_from_1 = dict_1[key]
item_from_2 = dict_2[key]
```

If you need to iterate dict_1, then on each item find the appropriate item in the second, then this also needs to go over the key:

```
for (key,value1) in dict_1.iteritems():
    value2 = dict_2[key]
     .....
```

Note that the order the items come up in the loop may vary. Even from one run of the program to the next.